# What are the underlying assumptions of MA, AR & ARMA processes, formally & informally and how do we test them?

Tags: arima, references, assumptions, autoregressive, moving-average

I am new to the community and have recently started exploring time series analysis. I have seen a lot of answers here speak about how one tends to not focus on underlying assumptions and rather directly jumps to modelling. I tried finding for assumptions for MA, AR and ARMA processes, but couldn't find any formal set of assumptions! I seek for these processes, their formal assumptions with math supporting it wherever possible, some informal version of those assumptions **iff** they're too technical and a set of tests or procedures to find out whether those assumptions hold.

*Just as an example*, for Simple Linear Regression I'd roughly say(don't know much myself):

1. A linear relationship exists between the dependent & the independent variable -- R-squared
2. The independent variable is uncorrelated with the residuals -- ???
3. The expected value of the residual term is zero -- ???
4. The variance of the residual term is constant for all observations -- ???
5. The residual term is independently & normally distributed -- Omnibus/Jarque-Bera/QQPlot

Listing some of the places I have tried so far:

- [https://www.math.utah.edu/~zhorvath/ar1.pdf](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ezhorvath/ar1.pdf)
- [https://math.unm.edu/~ghuerta/tseries/week4_1.pdf](https://math.unm.edu/%7Eghuerta/tseries/week4_1.pdf)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Example:_An_AR(1)_process
- [http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs3750/lectures/class16.pdf](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/%7Emilos/courses/cs3750/lectures/class16.pdf)
- [https://mcs.utm.utoronto.ca/~nosedal/sta457/pacf.pdf](https://mcs.utm.utoronto.ca/%7Enosedal/sta457/pacf.pdf)